# TypeError: could not convert

Tags: python, pyside

Using `python`, `pyside`, I get this error:

```
    self.setCheckState(value)
TypeError: could not convert 'BooleanEditor' to 'QCheckBox'
```

Beside that many of Google's result only show "TypeError: **can** not convert" instead of "**could**", I still have no idea how to fix this.

Code snippet:

```
class Editor(QGraphicsLayoutItem): 
    def __init__(self, name):
        QGraphicsLayoutItem.__init__(self)
        :
    :
    def update_value(self, value):
        pass

class BooleanEditor(Editor, QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, name, value, min, max):
        Editor.__init__(self, name)
        QCheckBox.__init__(self)

        self.update_value(value)

    def update_value(self, value):
        self.old_value = value
        self.setCheckState(value)  # Error occurs here.
```

"value" that setCheckState receives will be [Qt.CheckState](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/Qt.html?highlight=qt.checkstate#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.Qt.CheckState). Upon running, the "value" is `Qt.Unchecked` (== 0) as expected, according to debug printing.

Notice that `BooleanEditor` employs `multiple inheritance`. I'm porting `wxWidget` app (that someone else made) to `Qt`, and for now I don't want to change this design because this comes from original (meaning mult inheritance itself here shouldn't be the cause since the original app works fine).

Environment) pyside 1.1.0, python 2.7.3, Ubuntu 12.04

---

Update-1) As @Luke Woodward suggests, I tried to swap the order of super classes as `BooleanEditor(QCheckBox, Editor)`, then get a different error at different part.

```
class PaneGroup(GroupView, QFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, group, config, top = None):
        GroupView.__init__(self, group, top) 
        QFrame.__init__(self)
        :
        sizer = QGraphicsGridLayout()
        :        
        for param_descr in self.params:
            name = param_descr['name']
            type, val, min, max, description = param_descr['type'], config[name], param_descr['min'], param_descr['max'], param_descr['description']
            try:
                enum = eval(param_descr['edit_method'])['enum']
                editor = self.top.EnumEditor(self, name, val, enum)
            except:
                editor = self.top._editor_types[type](self, name, val, min, max)
            self.top.editors[name] = editor
            sizer.addItem(editor, row, 1) # Error occurs here
```

Error:

```
TypeError: could not convert 'BooleanEditor' to 'QGraphicsLayoutItem'
```

Looks like an issue about initialization in multiple inheritance to me..

Comment: Does it help if you change the order of `BooleanEditor`s superclasses (i.e. write `class BooleanEditor(QCheckBox, Editor):`)?

Comment: Great question, the only thing it's lacking is an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). Note that [`setCheckState`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QCheckBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QCheckBox.setCheckState) does *not* take a boolean, but that's probably not the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with [this example](https://gist.github.com/3709893) on my system (pyside 1.1.3, python 2.7.3, debian sid). If you run the example code on your system, can *you* reproduce the `can not convert` error?

Comment: @phihag I got the same error that you commented out in your code example, but I don't get `cannot convert` error...hmm

Comment: @IsaacS Can you create a [gist](http://gist.github.com) of your **complete** original code? It's hard to solve a problem in a program we only see a tiny part of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My very bad, it turned out I was using `PyQt4` instead of `PySide`. When I use `PySide`, error doesn't occur (as @phihag's gist shows) whereas using `PyQt4` yields the same result. It's actually curious but I won't investigate further now.

Use the following code for reproduction.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import sys
from PySide.QtCore import Qt
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QCheckBox, QGraphicsLayoutItem
#from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
#from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QCheckBox, QGraphicsLayoutItem

class Editor(QGraphicsLayoutItem):
    def __init__(self, name):
        QGraphicsLayoutItem.__init__(self)
    def update_value(self, value):
        pass

class BooleanEditor(Editor, QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, value):
        Editor.__init__(self, "foo")
        QCheckBox.__init__(self)

        self.update_value(value)

    def update_value(self, value):
        self.old_value = value
        self.setCheckState(value) # Error occurs here
        print("End of update_value")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    BooleanEditor(Qt.Checked)
```

PS. Why I didn't know I was using `PyQt`? For which one I use, I'm depending on this framework I've been working with (called [`qt_gui`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/qt_gui_core) in [`ROS`, Robot Operating System](http://www.ros.org/wiki/)), which doesn't explicitly tells me which one in use (it's open source prj and documentation work is ongoing)...After hacking into its codes, I figured out default is `PyQt`.